# Injectivity using complex cubics.

Tags: functions

[image]

I've got this question and I've never been taught about injectivity with regards to complex numbers.

If it were for real numbers then I would find the value of alpha such that the derivative never changes sign but because its complex, I'm not sure how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are dealing with a complex cubic polynomial, we know we have three roots with some possibly repeated. A necessary (but not sufficient) condition for $h$ to be injective is that all three roots are equal. Since certainly $0$ is a root, the only possible case is $\alpha=0$, i.e. $h(z)=z^3$. It is not difficult to show that this function is not injective.

As an exercise, you might like to try to generalise this result for a complex polynomial of degree $n\geq2$.